# On mobile phone text goes smaller around PayPal pay button. Stays same size on desktop

Tags: html, paypal

On a desktop computer the fonts around a PayPal pay button stay the same.

On a mobile phone the fonts resize smaller around a PayPal button. How do I fix this using basic html?

such as: `font color="#151B8D" size="4" face="verdana,arial,helvetica"`

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear but i know what you want ! yes it is occure but you should be specify your media screen in css like

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
 }
}
```

for both style Mobile and Pc read more about @media at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)